# Filter Dates / Search dates in table jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've found this code on a website called w3schools and it will filter any text values that matches the value of the input field here's the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Johnny</td>
    <td>Depp</td>
    <td>2022-06-03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Angelina</td>
    <td>Jolie</td>
    <td>2022-06-04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Parker</td>
    <td>2022-06-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lebron</td>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>2022-06-06</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

**My question is can we do this on input date? i just wanted to search dates i tried to change the  type to date but it just doesn't work, is there any ways to do this?**

Ex:

```
<input id="myInput" type="date" placeholder="Search..">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="date" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Johnny</td>
    <td>Depp</td>
    <td>2022-06-03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Angelina</td>
    <td>Jolie</td>
    <td>2022-06-04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Parker</td>
    <td>2022-06-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lebron</td>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>2022-06-06</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine if you change the value with the keyboard

if you want it to run when selecting a date then change it with the 'change' event : same as

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("change", function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(value)
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myInput" type="date" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Johnny</td>
    <td>Depp</td>
    <td>2022-06-03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Angelina</td>
    <td>Jolie</td>
    <td>2022-06-04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Parker</td>
    <td>2022-06-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lebron</td>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>2022-06-06</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, this is exacly what im looking. it works fine now